# Bigcommerce https error for one image

Tags: ssl, https, bigcommerce

I get an error for the first image it loads in my mega menu but all the other images load fine and use https  it just loads the first one using http

the site is http://www.thepeakskiandsports.com

The code for the navigation menu is as follows

```html
{{#if children}}
<a class="navPages-action has-subMenu" href="{{url}}" data-collapsible="navPages-{{id}}">
    {{name}} <i class="icon navPages-action-moreIcon" aria-hidden="true"><svg><use xlink:href="#icon-chevron-down" /></svg></i>
</a>
<div class="navPage-subMenu" id="navPages-{{id}}" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1">
        <ul class="navPage-subMenu-list">
        <div class="imageArea colLeft">
            <!-- Error happens on the next line but only for the first item loaded-->            
            <a class="navPage-subMenu-action navPages-action" href="{{url}}"><span>{{lang 'category.view_all.name' category=name}}</span> <img src="{{getImage image "thumbnail"}}"  alt="{{name}}">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="navPage-subMenu-container">  
        {{#each children}}
            <li class="navPage-subMenu-item">
                {{#if children}}
                    <a
                        class="navPage-subMenu-action navPages-action has-subMenu"
                        href="{{url}}"
                        data-collapsible="navPages-{{id}}"
                        data-collapsible-disabled-breakpoint="medium"
                        data-collapsible-disabled-state="open"
                        data-collapsible-enabled-state="closed">
                        {{name}} <i class="icon navPages-action-moreIcon" aria-hidden="true"><svg><use xlink:href="#icon-chevron-down" /></svg></i>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="navPage-childList" id="navPages-{{id}}">
                        {{#each children}}
                        <li class="navPage-childList-item">
                            <a class="navPage-childList-action navPages-action" href="{{url}}">{{name}}</a>
                        </li>
                        {{/each}}
                    </ul>
                {{else}}
                    <a class="navPage-subMenu-action navPages-action" href="{{url}}">{{name}}</a>
                {{/if}}
            </li>
        {{/each}}
        </div>
    </ul>
</div>
{{else}}
<a class="navPages-action" href="{{url}}">{{name}}</a>
{{/if}}
```

Comment: What happens when you delete that image? Does it load the "next" first image on http?
Also is there a reason to run your entire storefront on SSL?

Comment: yes it loads the next first image on http.  Yes because it is required for SSL compliance and for the certificate to show the site as secure on all modern browsers now.

Comment: I have always found this as a headache to bootstrap the entire site with SSL because of the performance tax. That's why I was asking.

In this case you may want to try hardcoding the menu. Or maybe create an array with SSL URLS and iterate them via stencil instead of iterating thumbnails alone. 
I happened to notice that Bigcommerce is not the place to seek rational approach at all times.